# Can I only use POST for calling json-rpc endpoints?

Tags: json, http, json-rpc

When using json-rpc over http. Should I just be using POST for calling endpoints? or is it also possible to use other http methods like PUT.

Comment: Of course you could use other methods. However, the point of RPC is that you define your own vocabulary instead of mapping arbitrary operations to the vocabulary of HTTP.

Comment: I actually found this document, http://www.jsonrpc.org/historical/json-rpc-over-http.html and it suggests that the proper way is either by GET or POST. But it says that POST is the preferred method.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure that's authoritative since there are a lot of ad hoc JSON RPC systems out there but if you are going to pick one, then you have to pick POST.